# Reference for constant sectional curvature manifolds being locally isometric

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, curvature

I am looking for a reference (or a good proof) for the fact that two Riemannian manifolds of same constant sectional curvature are locally isometric.

Comment: *Riemannian Geometry* by Gallot, Hulin and Lafontaine, second edition, chapter 3, section F, Theorem 3.82 and its corollary in remark (pages 160 and 161).

Comment: This is also not hard to prove using the machinery of moving frames and differential forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Riemannian Manifold: An Introduction to Curvature* by John M. Lee, proposition 10.10, page 181.

Comment: Note that this reference is to the old first edition of my book. A better reference is to the newer second edition, titled _Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds_, Corollary 10.15.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(e_1, \dots, e_m)$ be a local orthonormal frame on $M$, with dual frame $(\omega^1, \dots, \omega^m)$. Let $\omega^i_j = -\omega^j_i$, $1 \le i,j \le m$, be the connection $1$-forms. These satisfy the Maurer-Cartan equations
\begin{align*}
d\omega^i + \omega^i_j\wedge\omega^j &= 0
\end{align*}
If $M$ has constant sectional curvature $K$, then they also satisfy
$$
d\omega^i_j + \omega^i_k\wedge\omega^k_j = K\omega^i\wedge\omega^j.
$$
Let $(f_1, \dots, f_m)$ be a local orthonormal frame on $N$, with dual frame $(\theta^1, \dots, \theta^m)$ and connection $1$-forms $\theta^i_j$. If $N$ has constant sectional curvature $K$, then these forms also satisfy the equations above.

On $M\times N$, consider the following differential system:
\begin{align*}
\eta^i &= \omega^i - \theta^i = 0\\
\eta^i_j &= \omega^i_j - \theta^i_j = 0
\end{align*}
The Frobenius theorem states that if on $M\times N$, there exist $1$-forms $\alpha^i_j, \alpha^{ik}_j, \beta^{i}_{jk}, \beta^{ik}_{jl}$ such that
\begin{align*}
d\eta^i &= \alpha^i_j\wedge \eta^j + \alpha^{ik}_j\wedge\eta^j_k\\
d\eta^i_j &= \beta^i_{jk}\wedge\eta^k + \beta^{ik}_{jl}\wedge\eta^l_k,
\end{align*}
then, given any $(p,q) \in M\times N$, there exists an $m$-dimensional submanifold $\Sigma$ passing through $(p,q)$ on which the differential system holds. $\Sigma$ is necessarily the graph of an map $\Phi: M \rightarrow N$ such that $\Phi^*\theta^i = \omega^i$, $1 \le i \le m$. This implies $\Phi$ is an isometry.

It remains to verify the conditions required by the Frobenius theorem. However, this is straightforward.

Comment: Very useful answer, thanks. Could you give me a reference for this?

Comment: @Jotabeta, unfortunately I don't know of any reference for this. There are two introductory books to exterior differential systems, one by Jeanne Clelland and the other by Ivey and Landsberg. I glanced at the second one, and it appears to be an exercise. These books do present all of the necessary ingredients, from which the result is easily proved.